# Select the least number from database

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I am trying to run two queries within one I guess you could say.  What I am trying to do is build a scoring system where each person gets two chances.  The least number is their best.  What I need to have happen is for the php query to select the smallest number for each person, then display the 3 names of the people with the 3 smallest numbers.

I am guessing I need to use a query like this to get the smallest number for each person:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT LEAST(MIN(timeone),MIN(timetwo))FROM table1");
```

(maybe that code isn't right either)

but after this I am stumped as to how to make it display the names associated with the 3 smallest numbers.

all data is in the same table

so example

```
name    number1    number2
1        10           8
2         4           7
3         12          11
4         3            17
```

so it would determine the smallest number for name 1 is 8, name 2 is 4, name 3 is 11 and name 4 is 3.

It would then determine that the three smallest are name 1, name 2, name 4 and list them.

Comment: What if values are tied?

Answer (score 1):

So you can achieve this by using order and limit like this:

```
SELECT name,LEAST(number1,number2) as Smaller FROM table1
ORDER BY smaller 
LIMIT 3;
```

Or just to get their names:

```
SELECT name FROM table1
ORDER BY LEAST(number1,number2) 
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: No problem, if my answer helped you I'll appreciate if you approve it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be the best solution because Im not a dba myself, but you can use:

```
SELECT min(col_alias) AS min_value FROM (

    SELECT col1 AS col_alias FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col2 FROM yourtable

) vw
```

Another (better IMO) solution, would be select all the mins from yourtable and, then, use min function from php:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT min(col1) as minCol1, min(col2) AS minCol2 FROM yourtable");
$rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
$minNumber = min($rs);
```

Note: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. As alternative, you may use `mysqli_*` functions or migrate to **PDO**